# Can an Azure network interface be classified as a compute resource or is it simply a network resource?

Tags: azure

I'm a beginner with Azure and for cost analysis purposes I'm trying to classify all Azure resources as either Compute, Network, Security, or Data. I know the network interface allows a VM to communicate with Azure, the internet, and/or on-prem resources. Although it literally has network in the name, since the network interface runs on the VM directly could it be classified as a compute resource? What makes the most sense from a spend perspective? I know it may be a matter of semantics but I must choose the most relevant category for the sake of this project.

Answer (score 0):

I would define them as network, since the network requirements will determine the cost:

- You may have several network interfaces on one VM
- The cost of a network interface varies depending on the type of IP address (dynamic/static/public)